# Does google actually run our app on some emulator in playstore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I just uploaded an APK update on google playstore. 
The app sends out its FCMid to our server for push notifications.

i get instead of the regular FCMid, a string "BLACKLISTED" as the FCM registration token. It appears, this happens only when FCM runs on emulators.

So i checked my webserver logs and the request originated from United States, California, Mountain View

Any idea, why google / firebase actually would execute our app, instead of doing meta checks?

Comment: Did you upload to your alpha or beta channel? Because if so, you might be seeing the results of the pre-launch report, which indeed runs your app. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en

Comment: No, it was straight production APK update.